# Powerpoint : Animation Only Play First Time You Visit a Slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

On each of my slides are 'Timers' which display the time elapsed for that particular slide. I have built it in the Slide Master, interposing 15 shapes one on top of the next. Each shape appears after 1 min. The animations start with the slide, the maximum time which can be shown is 15 min (which is the 15th shape). It works very well.

However when I go back to a previous slide, the animations don't work, it just shows a static 15 min. Any way to overcome this. I have tried the 'Rewind Animation' functions, but it is no good. It just undoes the animations. I have 15 animation sequences.

In the current slide, if I click to proceed to the next slide, it does not go to the next slide, instead it end the animation. So two clicks are required. Any solution to this.

Info:

```
Powerpoint 2013 (32 Bit)
Windows 7 Professional (64 Bit)
```

Edit: I have tried adding the 'Timers' on the slides individually also, but to no avail. It would be great if others at least shared their tips on how they use timers,

Comment: I see you are still active and earned a Tumbleweed on this question.  Did you ever solve it or has it been overtaken by events?

Comment: Nope, yet to get my head round this. There were some solutions, but none to cater to my need.

Comment: Just as an experiment, have you tried doing it on each slide rather than the master?  If that doesn't fix it, add that information to the question, which will freshen it in the active questions list.